# Sorting datetime column when month is formatted as name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I have a column `Date Time` in my dataframe which has the date and time as a string.

```
Product       Date Time
ABC          Wed Jan 2 11:14:24 2019
ABC123       Wed Jan 2 11:14:24 2019
ABCXZY       Wed Jan 2 11:14:24 2019
BVF123       Mon Jan 14 10:24:20 2019
ABC456       Mon Jan 14 10:24:20 2019
ABC000       Mon Feb 4 10:44:08 2019
ABCXYZ       Mon Feb 4 10:44:08 2019
ABC678       Mon Feb 4 10:44:08 2019
ABCQYZ       Wed Feb 20 09:14:40 2019
ABC090       Wed Feb 20 09:14:40 2019
```

I have converted this column to a datetime format using -

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date Time']).dt.strtime('%d-%b-%Y')
```

I want to now sort this dataframe on the basis of the `Date` column to plot the quantities for each date in ascending order of date, but when I use -

```
df.sort_values(by='Date', inplace=True, ascending=True)
```

it only gets sorted by the date and ignores the month name, i.e as

```
02-Jan-2019
04-Feb-2019
08-Mar-2019
13-Feb-2019
14-Jan-2019
20-Feb-2019
21-Mar-2019
```

instead of

```
02-Jan-2019
14-Jan-2019
04-Feb-2019
13-Feb-2019
20-Feb-2019
08-Mar-2019
21-Mar-2019
```

How can I get the desired sorting using pandas datetime or any other module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Date Time']).dt.strtime('%d-%b-%Y')
```

returns a series of string ("object type" to be precise) but not a series of datetime. That's why your sorting is wrong.
Here is a code to do it :

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

### Dataframe    
data = {'Product' : ['ABC', 'ABC123', 'ABCXZY', 'BVF123', 'ABC456', 'ABC000', 'ABCXYZ', 'ABC678', 'ABCQYZ', 'ABC090'], 'Date Time' : ['Wed Jan 2 11:14:24 2019', 'Wed Jan 2 11:14:24 2019', 'Wed Jan 2 11:14:24 2019', 'Mon Jan 14 10:24:20 2019', 'Mon Jan 14 10:24:20 2019', 'Mon Feb 4 10:44:08 2019', 'Mon Feb 4 10:44:08 2019', 'Mon Feb 4 10:44:08 2019', 'Wed Feb 20 09:14:40 2019', 'Wed Feb 20 09:14:40 2019']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

### Conversion to datetime    
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:, 'Date Time'])

### Sorting
df.sort_values(by = 'Date', inplace = True)

### Plot    
ax = df.groupby('Date').count().Product.plot()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%b-%Y')) # Formatting x labels
```

Comment: When I plot this df using df.groupby(['Date']).count()['Product'].plot() the X-Axis doesn't show me the sorted date order... Does that mean I have to sort the date values after the groupby?

Comment: Could you add a sample of your 'df' dataframe in your initial post ?

Comment: Added sample dataframe above!

Answer (score 1):

We can do `argsort`

```
df=df.iloc[pd.to_datetime(df['Date Time'],format='%d-%b-%Y').argsort()]
Out[20]: 
     Date Time
3  14-Jan-2019
0  04-Feb-2019
2  13-Feb-2019
4  20-Feb-2019
1  08-Mar-2019
5  21-Mar-2019
```

Update

```
s=df.groupby(['Date Time']).size()
s.index=pd.to_datetime(s.index,format='%d-%b-%Y')
s.sort_index(inplace=True)
s.index=s.index.strftime('%d-%b-%Y')
```

Comment: When I plot this df using `df.groupby(['Date']).count()['Product'].plot()` the X-Axis doesn't show me the sorted date order... Does that mean I have to sort the date values after the groupby?

Comment: @harry04 you need do the sort after that . check the update

Comment: Now the second line `argsort()` gives me an `IndexError: positional index out-of-bounds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202079/discussion-between-harry04-and-wenyoben).